# What is alternative to deployUrl which renames chunk files?

Tags: angular, angular16, angular.json

I have specyfic build configuration, where .js files are placed in subfolder.

```
- index.html
- prod/
    - main.js
    - polyfils.js
    - lazy loaded chunks
```

Getting lazy chunks worked with deployUrl option.

```
 "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "deployUrl": "/prod/",
              ...
            }
 }
```

I'm trying to replace deployUrl option with recommended baseHref, but it doesn't change paths of lazy chunk files.

With `"deployUrl": "/prod/"` chunk files were like `/prod/6.hash.js` and it works.
With `"baseHref": "/prod/"` chunk files were like `/6.hash.js`, and it throws an error: file doesn't exist.

I've noticed that deployUrl adds the url inside runtime.js, but baseHref don't do that.
[image: runetime.js]

Is there any alternative for deployUrl which also changes the chunk files paths in runtime.js?